# Why does padding: 0 hide my unordered list bullets?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I'm updating an old site, with lots of unordered lists. Whenever padding is set to 0, the display 'marker' of the unordered list disappears.

The issue was the CSS setting `*{padding: 0; margin: 0;}` which I'm now removing, which, per [Chris Coyier's notes](https://css-tricks.com/margin-0-padding-0-no-longer-cool/), is "No Longer Cool".

Why does `padding: 0` cause the display of unordered list 'markers' to disappear?

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8ogvucku/2/)

```
<div> List of Stuff:
    <ul class="circle" >
         <li>Apples</li>
         <li>Bumblebees </li>
         <li>Cats</li>
         <li>Dogs</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-position: outside;
    padding: 0;    
    margin: 0px; 
}

ul li {
     background-repeat: no-repeat; 
     background-position: 0px center; 
     padding-left: 15px; 
}

ul.disc{
    list-style-type: disc;
}

ul.circle {
    list-style-type: circle;
}

ul.square {
    list-style-type: square;
}

ul.gray_quad li{
    list-style-image: url("./includes/images/gray_quad.gif")
}

ul.yellow_quad li{
    list-style-image: url("./includes/images/yellow_quad.gif")
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `list-style-position: outside`, the list markers are placed outside of the list item boxes. The padding on the unordered list element itself offsets the list items so that the markers can be seen. This is typically implemented as a browser default, nonzero value for `padding-left`. Zeroing out the padding causes the list item boxes themselves, which contain the text content, to align with the unordered list box, thus hiding the list markers.